# What does this symbol mean in the context of an analog digital converter?

Tags: adc

What does this symbol mean in the context of an analog digital converter?

[image]

whole circuit:

[image]

Steuerung: Control

Comment: This is not a "standard" symbol. My **guess** (which takes into account what the system is (an ADC) and what are the signals going into and out of the block) is that it is a **latch** which synchronizes the signal from the AND gate (&) with the a clock signal coming from the "Steuerung" (control) block. The signal from the AND gate can change state at **any time**. After this latch, it can only change state at for example the positive edge of the clock.

Comment: It's a pulse edge synchronizer.

Comment: Could be some sort of pulse gating. Thus the output is  a train of pulses which run as long as the output is high.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It represents a **counter** and the whole circuit is a [**dual-slope-ADC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter#Integrating).

The line coming from the AND-gate is the counter's clock pulse input.
The line coming from the "Steuerung" block is the counter's reset input.
The "Steuerung" block should also control S1 and S2.

For comparision see e.g. [here (page 20)](https://home.zhaw.ch/kunr/Elektronik2/Skript/AD_Wandler_v3.pdf):
[image]